# RMarkDown: Include many HTML pages with includeHTML()

Tags: html, r-markdown

I want to add external HTML pages into my Rmarkdown file. When I only add one page it works fine, but when I add more than one page the html rmarkdown output is break :

````
---
title: "Test"
output:
  html_document:
    includes:
      in_header: "header.html"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

```

## Test {.tabset}


### firstpage 
```{r, echo=FALSE}
    htmltools::includeHTML("firstpage.html")
```

### seconpage 
```{r, echo=FALSE}
    htmltools::includeHTML("secondpage.html")
```
````

I know that I have to only include the body section of my html pages because  adding all html section will create conflits with rmarkdown file, so I add "in_header: "header.html"" on top of the rmd file.

But the html pages that I want to add have all CSS and Javascript section describe in their head section, how I'm supposed to add these sections in the rmd file ?

Answer (score 0):

I never used rmarkdown before but from a fast check on google, your HTML files should not contain an HTML tags and should only be the parts that you want to add to the output file immediately.

For example:

- header.html: should only contain the JS and CSS libraries for your HTML file.
- Firstpage.html: should only contain the body HTML

Here is the resource for that: [rmarkdown cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/include-html.html) [GitHub issue](https://github.com/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/issues/69)

Based on that if the solution did not work, I think you may try to include the JS/CSS files inside the body itself and include that file.

like this:
**secondpage.html**

```html
<div>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <div id="container">he</div>
    some codes
</div>
```

By doing this you emit the head yet you are still able to use those files.
I used div instead of body cause one HTML file can have only one body.